# How to combine 2 arrays with the condition that 2 and 5 values will be from the second array?

Tags: php

There are two arrays:

```
$arrOne = [1, 3, 4];
$arrTwo = [2, 5,];
$newArr = [];
```

How to merge to get like this;

$newArr = [1, **2**, 3, 4, **5**];

Now displays through one, this option is not suitable.

```
foreach ($arrOne as $k => $v) {
 $newArr[] = $v;
 $newArr[] = $arrTwo[$k];
}
```

Here is another example. Tthe values can be different in the array.

```
$arrOne = [154, 32, 15]; 
$arrTwo = [682, 124,];
```

Again for this example it is necessary that the values from the second array always be at 2 and 5 positions in the new array:

```
$newArr = [154, 682, 32, 15, 124];
```

Comment: What this has to do with mysql or sql?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte

$arrOne = [154, 32, 15];
$arrTwo = [682, 124,];

$newArr = [154, 682, 32, 15, 124]; // How can you sort like this?

Comment: @РусланЛысенко You'll need to explain the logic behind that merge. Why does the first element of `$arrTwo` come in the second position of the result and the second element in the last position?

Comment: @Ivar I have 2 requests, one request displays posts with some data, the second request displays posts with different data.

I want to combine them into one array when outputting to the front. But, so that posts from the second array are displayed at positions 2 and 5.

Comment: So the arrays have always the same sizes, but values don't matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to merge the arrays in the intended way to the specific indices:

```
array_splice( $arrOne, 1, 0, $arrTwo[0]); 
array_splice( $arrOne, 4, 0, $arrTwo[1]);

var_dump($arrOne);
```

Demo 1:

Using original data:

```
$arrOne = [1, 3, 4];
$arrTwo = [2, 5,];
```

https://3v4l.org/dAMav

Demo 2:

Using second set of data:

```
$arrOne = [154, 32, 15]; 
$arrTwo = [682, 124,];
```

https://3v4l.org/Xhl3K

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge and sort functions to achieve this as following:

```
$newArr = array_merge($arrOne, $arrTwo);  // it will be [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]  
sort($newArr); // it will sort array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can use $newArr now which have sorted data

Comment: Yes, but the values can be different in the array.
```
$arrOne = [154, 32, 15];
$arrTwo = [682, 124,];

$newArr = [154, 682, 32, 15, 124];
```
For example such. It is necessary that the values from the second array always be at 2 and 5 positions in the new array.

Comment: you can put value at array index using array_splice like 
array_splice( $arrOne, 2, 0, $arrTwo[0]); array_splice( $arrOne, 4, 0, $arrTwo[1]);

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrOne = [1, 3, 4];
$arrTwo = [2, 5];
$newArr = [];
foreach($arrOne as $key => $one) {
    switch($key) {
        case 1: 
            $newArr[] = $arrTwo[0];
            break;
        case 4: 
            $newArr[] = $arrTwo[1];
            break;
    }
    $newArr[] = $one;
}
if(count($newArr) < 5) {
    $newArr[] = $arrTwo[1];
}
```

[Demo link](https://3v4l.org/9je5o)

Here we are considering there will be always two elements in second array

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayOne = [12,23,45,56,65,78,99];
$arrayTwo = [2,5];

$mergedArray = [];

foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
    
    $position = $key + 1;
    if ($position === 2) {

        $mergedArray[] = $arrayTwo[0];
    } else if ($position === 4) {

        $mergedArray[] = $arrayTwo[1];
    }

    $mergedArray[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).